# why does linker have a tougher task in C++ compared to C?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, linker

The interviewer asked me this question and not sure if my answer to it was good enough or not. Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: How did you reply to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thought that popped in my head was name mangling. In C++ but not in C, you can have two methods with the same name but different parameters. The compiler has to distinguish between the two methods and thus changes (mangles) the name internally.

Another thing that the C++ compiler must do that in not in C, is deal with the class inheritance. You have abstract classes, overridden methods and virtual methods. That takes a little more processing to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say I understand this very well, but this [blog entry by Ian Lance Taylor](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/50) seems to have an answer.  Quoting from there:

> There are some special challenges when using C++. Adding a new virtual method to a class can be an ABI change for any function which uses that class. Providing the backward compatible version of the class in such a situation is very awkward–there is no natural way to specify the name and version to use for the virtual table or the RTTI information for the old version.
>
> Naturally, you must never delete any symbols.

Read the entry for some more context.  (ABI = Application Binary Interface)